# How can I manage the DNS records of my website, which I host at home?

Tags: server, apache2, dns

I started a project a while ago, to create my own website and I wanted to get a feel of how it all worked so I decided to host it at home.

So I pulled out an old PC, threw Ubuntu server on it (currently running version 16.04.2 LTS) and created an account at no-ip.com to handle the dynamic IP given by my ISP. The website has been running like this (LAMP) for a while now.

Having started with zero knowledge of Linux or HTML, I decided to treat myself to a cheap domain name (*.eu at Godaddy) to substitute the uglier domains that come with a free no-ip.com account.

So far, I have only managed to point the Godaddy domain to the no-ip.com domain, which isn't much of an improvement. Both Godaddy and no-ip.com offer paid plans to manage the DNS for me. However, I wouldn't want to start paying for services now and I would like to figure out how it works.

Up until now, Google searches and forum threads have carried me through everything from Linux to CSS but I must admit I am a bit stuck. When I search for how to configure a DNS server I only get results on how to change the DNS server my computer uses to resolve names into IPs. Correct me if I am wrong, but what I think I need is to change the record on the DNS servers *everybody else uses* to resolve names into IPs so that I can use my .eu domain only and bypass no-ip.com completely. First of all, is this the right question to ask? If so, is it possible to do from behind an ISP router without paying a third party?

Sorry for the long post and thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. This problem is not really Ubuntu specific and should be better placed in other communities. In Serverfault answers exist: https://serverfault.com/q/394378/390909

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and sorry about the question not being Ubuntu-specific. Thanks too, for pointing me towards serverfault.com, there's a lot that is new for me there, but it will get me going in the right direction, I've been stuck on this for a while... Regarding the question, should I delete it from here? Mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists no common way to update DNS records, but GoDaddy provides an [API](https://developer.godaddy.com/doc#!/_v1_domains/recordAdd) to do that. You could write your own script or use a [ready-made one](https://github.com/CarlEdman/godaddy-ddns) to use it from your Ubuntu Server.

Get some more information from the same question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/394378/390909).